Karabiner keys remaping with different language source
Problem with the Karabiner complex rule
I use a Cyrillic layout on the US keyboard, for using a slash I have to change the layout every very annoying time. I tried to use Karabiner with a complex rule for remapping keys but it doesn't work.

    {
      "description": "Slash to Shift+Backslash",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "conditions": [
            {
            "type": "input_source_if",
            "input_sources": 
              [
                {
                  "language": "uk"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "from": {
            "key_code": "42",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory":[
                "shift"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "slash"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }


Welcome to Ask Different.  Why do you specify an input source language of UK in this script?

@bmike To make the story short, I bought a macbook with ANSI keyboard and now I don't have a slash in Ukrainian layout. Every time to put slash I have to change layout to EN and back. I need to map hotkey for slash in UK layout
